# How can I transform my code to get a dropbox instead of text?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have this code in my web site, it is in php. People provided from a form the total duration time of a tour.

```
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-left">Total Hour Duration</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="tourdays" value="<?php echo @$tdata[0]->tour_days; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to transform this and have a drop box that they can choose numbers from 1 to 12.

How can I create a dropbox and let them choose only one option ?

Comment: Use `<select>` to create a dropdown menu.

Comment: This is basic HTML, has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: but my code is in php and it wrights everything to a database. How can have multiple options but eventually get the one picked. I am sorry but my knowledge is limited. I got this opensourse code for my site but i need to transform it.

Comment: You need to read an HTML tutorial that shows how to create forms with dropdown menus. `<select name="tourdays"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>...</select>`

Comment: The PHP that fills in the database from this doesn't change, `$_POST['tourdays']` will contain the option that was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Barmar in your the comments, you would need to use a select

```
<select name="tourdays">
<option value="1">1</option>
...
</select>
```

Then with your form, make sure Its method is POST. (Again, Barmar says this in the comments)

```
<form action="./submitForm.php" method="POST">
```

Then on the action page, you would have something like this

```
$database->query('INSERT INTO table (tourdays) VALUES (?)', $_POST['tourdays']);
```

This is just an example, but should give you a visual representation of what to do,

A form like this is 100% HTML and the PHP would only come in once you submit it using POST, either to itself, or another page (Like I used in the example)

And if you plan to post to the same page you would need someting like this

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  //Action POST Data here
}
```